# how to update user avatar in XMPPvCardAvatarModule swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using XMPPFramework for chating in my iOS App but i need to update User avatar while user updating there profile picture but i don't have any idea how i implement this this . I Implement XMPPvCardAvatarModule and XMPPvCardTempModule but i did not understand how i pass the user picture in these module for other user . And after updating the picture all user get XMPP notification for Avatar update.

Any one have idea please share with me i am new on XMPP.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change login user Avatar image by

```
#pragma mark - Update avatar image Methode.
-(void)changeUserImage:(UIImage*)image {

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //Create XML for first time VCARD Save.
        NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
        NSXMLElement *photoXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
        NSXMLElement *typeXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"TYPE"stringValue:@"image/jpeg"];

        //Convert image to bbase64String
        NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

        NSXMLElement *binvalXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL" stringValue:base64String];

        [photoXML addChild:typeXML];
        [photoXML addChild:binvalXML];
        [vCardXML addChild:photoXML];

        //Update user avatar on local database.
        XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [[[XmppHandler sharedInstance] xmppvCardTempModule]myvCardTemp];
        NSLog(@"%@",myvCardTemp);

        if (myvCardTemp) {
            [myvCardTemp setPhoto:imageData];
            [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp
             :myvCardTemp];

        } else {

            XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
            [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
        }
    });
}
```